# Grade sync failing after adding a library

Tags: android

This is the library I am using: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

The grade sync fails after adding it. Before that, there is no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the library you are using uses an older version of the support library v25.3.1, and it is conflicting with the one you have.
Try the following:

```
compile ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

However there are no guarantees that the library would work considering a different version.

Comment: What about what the error message is suggesting? Would you take a look at my AndroidManifest.xml? I am not sure what to edit there

Comment: It should go shall you add the exclude part

Comment: You are right. It does not work. I have downgraded the support library back to v25.3.1 and it seems to be okay now.

Comment: Can use the new library https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper